# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain.chains.question_answering' on Linode server using python 3.7.3 and langchain 0.0.27

Tags: python-3.x, langchain, linode, py-langchain

I have made a Flask app, tested it on a local server and it works fine. Rented a server from Linode and wanted to deploy it there but ran into problems. Created a virtual environment just like I did on my computer, but the python version is 3.7.3 instead of 3.10.6. The langchain version is 0.0.27. These are the imports I need:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import openai
import pinecone
import json
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone 
import os
```

but when I run the app I get the error from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain.chains.question_answering'. Any help would be appriciated.

I have tried to update python and langchain, restart the server, delete the server and set up a new one, delete the venv and uninstall both langchain and python but to no avail. These are the libraries in my venv

```
 pip list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
aiohttp            3.8.5
aiosignal          1.3.1
annotated-types    0.5.0
async-timeout      4.0.2
asynctest          0.13.0
attrs              23.1.0
certifi            2023.7.22
charset-normalizer 3.2.0
click              8.1.6
dnspython          2.3.0
Flask              2.2.5
frozenlist         1.3.3
greenlet           2.0.2
gunicorn           21.2.0
idna               3.4
importlib-metadata 6.7.0
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.2
langchain          0.0.27
loguru             0.7.0
MarkupSafe         2.1.3
multidict          6.0.4
numpy              1.21.6
openai             0.27.8
packaging          23.1
pinecone-client    2.2.1
pip                23.2.1
pkg_resources      0.0.0
pydantic           1.10.9
pydantic_core      2.3.0
python-dateutil    2.8.2
PyYAML             6.0.1
requests           2.31.0
setuptools         68.0.0
six                1.16.0
SQLAlchemy         2.0.19
tqdm               4.65.0
typing_extensions  4.7.1
urllib3            2.0.4
Werkzeug           2.2.3
yarl               1.9.2
zipp               3.15.0
```

Comment: video on langchain: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygehmBjwtiw

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I deleted the venv, installed python 3.10.6 manually and created a venv with that. Now it runs properly.